# How do I fix this Wide & Deep RNN?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Working through the book Hands-On Machine Learning and came across the Wide and Deep model, which seems like a flexible, accurate RNN model. However, I keep getting the following error: " AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim' ". I Googled the error and there doesn't appear to be a clear solution or explanation for why I'm getting the error, at least to me as a beginner. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

```
housing = fetch_california_housing()

X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target, 
random_state=42)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid = scaler.transform(X_valid)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

input_A = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5], name="wide_input")
input_B = keras.layers.Input(shape=[6], name="deep_input")
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(input_B)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(hidden1)
concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="output")(concat)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_A, input_B], outputs=[output])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3))

X_train_A, X_train_B = X_train[:, :5], X_train[:, 2:]
X_valid_A, X_valid_B = X_valid[:, :5], X_valid[:, 2:]
X_test_A, X_test_B = X_test[:, :5], X_test[:, 2:]
X_new_A, X_new_B = X_test_A[:3], X_test_B[:3]

history = model.fit((X_train_A, X_train_B), y_train, epochs=20,
                validation_data=((X_valid_A, X_valid_B), y_valid))
mse_test = model.evaluate((X_test_A, X_test_B), y_test)
y_pred = model.predict((X_new_A, X_new_B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change shape=[5] to shape=(5) and same thing for shape=[6]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Keras version and its dependency on tensorflow.

If you are importing Keras like:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

And if version is 2.X.X It won't be a problem.

I tested on my Kaggle Notebook, it works on this version: other versions have some changes on concatanete part.

If you have importing like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

And if version is 2.X.X-tf It might be problematic.